# One line PPAM add-in causes PowerPoint 2013 to crash

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I have a user with a brand new machine with Win 7 x64 SP1 (6.1.7601), downgraded from Win 8, on it plus Office 365 Small Business Premium with PowerPoint 2013 32 bit (15.0.4649.1000).

I am debugging a PPAM add-in and have narrowed it down to a very bizarre situation I've never seen before:

1. Create a new PowerPoint file
2. Open the VBE, insert a module and add a one line sub as below
3. Save it as a PPAM
4. Load the PPAM add-in and see the message
5. Close PowerPoint
6. Open PowerPoint and it crashes with the message "Microsoft PowerPoint has stopped working" and the sub-text "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."
7. I kill PowerPoint and when running again am asked the usual question if I want to disable the "offending" add-in

What on earth can cause such behaviour? No other PPAM add-ins are running and I have tried with all COM add-ins disabled and with running powerpnt /safe

My one line test sub inside the PPAM:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
  MsgBox "It works"
End Sub
```

Btw, the full (and very complex) add-in works perfectly when loaded in its source PPTM form.

Answer (score 0):

Badly written COM add-ins can cause this kind of thing, where PPT crashes at shutdown or startup and points the Fickle Finger of Blame at whatever PPA/PPAM add-in is closest at the time.

I'd have them disable any COM add-ins other than the MS-supplied ones, which I've never run into any troubles with, then try again.

The "Win7 downgraded from Win8" bit makes me nervous too, but I can't toss any experientialia at you about it.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Yes, I've never understood the "pointing the finger" algorithm that MS runs when starting an Office App! It seems to be partly alphanumerically driven based on the add-in name. I already tried disabling all (both) COM add-ins ("Google Desktop Office Addin" and "oomfo charts for PowerPoint") and it didn't make any difference so I too am left suspecting the OS change.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already asked if they have Kaspersky?
Do they have any other ppa / ppam add ins (maybe hidden one from HKLM

Comment: Kaspersky? Is that a known invader of Office add-ins? I didn't see any other PPA/PPAM add-ins in the PowerPoint Options UI.

Comment: Ah. This Kaspersky issue! http://forum.kaspersky.com/lofiversion/index.php/t277011.html I have asked the user which AV suite they are using and am awaiting a response from tests with all AV disabled.

Comment: Office reinstalled and AV disabled. Still not working :-( The user says "we purchased the [Office] software from Godaddy or it actually came with our email business plan setup. I downloaded it from office 365"

Comment: I wonder if it's anything to do with the fact that my About PowerPoint states "Part of Microsoft Office 365" and the user's states "Part of Microsoft Office 365 Small Business Premium" and that appears to have been discontinued as per the last FAQ on this page : http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/business/office-365-small-business-premium-office-online-FX103037625.aspx

Comment: Just had an online chat session with Microsoft support but didn't get anywhere apart from being given a number to speak to a "real" PowerPoint specialist (1-800-642-7676)

Comment: If they have got Kaspersky even disabling wont kill the problem but it usually hits ppa files